# Pascal | Initializing variables

Tags: variables, pascal, freepascal

The following syntax examples are incorrect ways to initialize a variable in pascal:

```
var current: string = '1.6';
```

Error message: Column 21: Semicolon (;) expected.

```
var current: string;
current = '1.6';
```

Error message: Column 1: Duplicate identifier 'current'.

**Correct** syntax to initialize a variable in Pascal:

```
var current: string;
    begin
current := '1.6';
    end
```

Source:
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refse25.html#x56-740004.5

Comment: Perhaps a text book might help. Trying to guess your way to knowledge is unlikely to yield much of use.

Comment: My friendly advice is to read about elementary syntax rules in the Freepascal documentation. It will save you a lot of time and prevent frustration.

Comment: Never in a million years would a programmer realize to type "void Main(void) to start a program, yet this is the magic that declares it in C. Python doesn't know how to declare the end of a function and return a value. Many languages use return, which is so much goto. Scattering variable declarations throughout a program is terrible for CPU and memory in any language, because of how computers work. First syntax is actually correct - as you would have found out, if only you had bothered to look up a single programming example to know how!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't codified in Pascal for a long time, but the assignation of a variable uses the `:=` operator (assigment operator), `=` operator is for comparisitions. Otherwise you need to add the main program block, like this:

```pascal
Var
   current: string;

Begin
   current := '1.6';
End.
```

I hope can be useful for you.

More info here: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse101.html

Comment: Thanks, your link provided the answer:      var current: string;      begin     current := '1.6';       end

Comment: Sorry, i didn't remember that exists a var block and a main program block. i'm gonna edit the asnwer.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a very long time since I wrote Pascal, but IIRC, the assignment operator is `:=` (aka the walrus sign). `=` is the equality test operator.

Try this:

```
var current: string;
current := '1.6';
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also leads to the "duplicate identifier" error.